# Make all APK inactive instead unpublishing the App itself

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

In play Store developer console is there any options available to make all APK inactive. I want that user should not able to download app from play Store for a while. I don't want to unpublish the app.

I have not found any options in release management. Is it possible to make my app unavailable for some time? Don't want to delete app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make it clearer for you.

`UNPUBLISHING` app is not DELETING your app permanently. It is actually EXACTLY what you want. If you unpublish your app, it will be unavailable for new users to download your app, but still available for current users to use (play) or to get your app updated. When you want to make your app (apps) available again, just change its status from `unpublished` to `published`, then all users now can access it again. Moreover, by doing so, it will keep all of your apps' ratings, number of installs as before it was unpublished.

So if you want to make your app unavailable for some time (or make users unable to download your apps for some time), just make them `unpublished`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

No. Making the App inactive is precisely the purpose of unpublishing. You cannot prevent existing users from installing the APK, as then if they got a new phone they would be stuck without the app, and a user should ideally be able to move phones without affecting their app experience.